# Firefox: first DOM action after appending big tree awfully slow

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I have the following JS pseudo code:

```
var tree = $('<div id="root"></div>');
tree = build_big_tree();   // appends ~250 rows / 3000 DOM elements incl. 1 <audio> per row
$('body').append(tree);
some_DOM_call();
```

The code runs fine across browsers, but on firefox (13, on Ubuntu), `some_DOM_call()` is incredibly slow (about 10s for 250 rows, when the whole JS runs in under 1s).
I found this using `console.timeStamp()` in the code until I found the culprit.

The 10s are roughly proportional to the number of rows. Actual page is at http://wikiotics.org/fr/FSI-French-basic-course-revised-volume-01-unit-01-lesson-01?view=edit

Besides the time it takes, the most annoying part is that the whole browser becomes unusable for those 10s, even other tabs.

some_DOM_call() is originally jQuery code, but I narrowed it down to `elem.offsetWidth` (in jQuery cssHooks() for the curious). When I commented out some_DOM_call(), the following DOM access caused the 10s delay (`body.appendChild(OBJECT)`). So it doesn't seem to matter what I do, as long as it's a DOM related action, it will take the hit.

Firebug doesn't show me what's going on during those 10s, so I can only guess it's related to rendering the tree I inserted in the page. But I might be wrong.

How can I figure out what is actually going on, so I can improve things?

Comment: What happens when you remove the <audio> tag from each row?

Comment: good point. With no audio (or just 1), it loads in less than 3s, and no freezing.

Comment: So <audio> would be the culprit? I must mention that it is set to not preload audio?

Comment: I'm don't know much about the audio tag but it sounds like Firefox doesn't support no preload, is ignoring it for some reason, or has some other issue with multiple audio elements in the same document.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be an actual link to the page here...  What's happening during those 10s is presumably layout.  Why it takes so long is an interesting question, but hard to answer without seeing the actual HTML involved.

Comment: Forgot to mention, all the code is closure compiled. Readable code is at: https://gitorious.org/ductus/ductus/blobs/master/ductus/static/modules/flashcards/js/flashcard_deck_editor.js Line 946 adds the big tree, 947 causes the 10s delay.

Comment: @LaurentS Thanks for the link!  This looks like a bug in the audio controls implementation in Firefox; I filed https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=766811 .  In the meantime, does using fixed layout for the table help at all?